# remove a letter from a char and reprint the char

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, char

```
main(void)
{
 int p;
 char n[6]="apple";
 char n2[6]="happy";
 for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
         for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
             {
                 if(n[i]==n2[j])
                      // I want n2[j] removed
                      printf("%c",n2[j]);
                      break;
             }
     }
}
```

i want n2[j] to be removed from the char.
example : In this case n[0]=n2[1],i.e **a**=**a**. i want 'a' to be removed from the word.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: And when you "remove" it, your array will be 5 elements long and when you try to access the 6th element for comparison you'll walk off the end of the array and possibly get a [segfault](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj). Or maybe rather than remove you mean replace with something else?

Comment: Add more details for better undestanding of fellow SO members.

Answer (score 1):

This prints the char about to be removed and moves all chars in n2 after n2[j] up to and including null terminator back one byte, including the null terminator. String length is measured on each loop, so you won't loop past the first null terminator. main() should return int also.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //char n[6] = "apple";
    //char n2[6] = "happy";
    char n[] = "abcdefghij";
    char n2[] = "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(n); i++)     // You shouldn't loop the size of the array
                                            // but the size of the string, because
                                            // you wouldn't want to remove the null 
                                            // terminator
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(n2); j++) // Same here 
        {
            if (n[i] == n2[j])
            {
                printf("Removing char %c \n", n2[j]);
                memmove(&n2[j], &n2[j + 1], strlen(n2) - j);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nn2 = %s", n2);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to print the char AFTER removing it, then just print n[i], because inside the "if" block n[i] is guaranteed to be n2[j].